# How do i set up 2 differently sized columns with multipage support?

Tags: minipage, columns

I am trying to create a resume with two columns. I first looked at using minipage, but it doesn't support multiple pages (if text gets too long for one page). Is there any alternatives for minipage that supports multiple pages? The main thing I am looking for is 2 columns of different sizes that both have multipage support

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The `parcolumns` package seems to be able to do that.

Comment: Thank you @Bernard! That seemed to work, I will post an example for others to use!